# Prevent combat damages dealt with trample

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If a creature with trample attacks me and I block with a creature on which damages are prevented, will I receive extra damage over my creature toughness?

Examples: [Undergrowth Champion](https://magiccards.info/bfz/en/197.html), [Wall of Shadows](https://magiccards.info/ch/en/13.html)

Comment: Please do not change links to gatherer links because they are not compatible with non english browsers.

Comment: Gather links are more friendly with browsers and what is supported by the site. There is a request on meta to use a different site for the links but as of now the links that you are using are less friendly for users as they do not by default use a popup or open a new tab.

Comment: @JoeW, as long as you have an english browser, you don't mind about other users but gatherer links have no interest for them. I added this request on meta.

Comment: You may want to consider accepting my answer if it has sufficiently answered your question.

Comment: @NeilMeyer ok, I did. I found the rule 510.1c mentioned in the duplicate usefull too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, the attacking player only has to assign enough damage to the blocking creature for the attack to be lethal, that means damage equal to all the blocking creature's toughness, whether the creatures actually die from combat damage is not strictly necessary. There may be a myriad of ways in which damage may be prevented, but that does not change how the damage is assigned.

> 702.19b. The controller of an attacking creature with trample first assigns damage to the creature(s) blocking it. Once all those blocking
>   creatures are assigned lethal damage, any remaining damage is assigned
>   as its controller chooses among those blocking creatures and the
>   player or planeswalker the creature is attacking. When checking for
>   assigned lethal damage, take into account damage already marked on the
>   creature and damage from other creatures that's being assigned during
>   the same combat damage step, but not any abilities or effects that
>   might change the amount of damage that's actually dealt. The attacking
>   creature's controller need not assign lethal damage to all those
>   blocking creatures but in that case can't assign any damage to the
>   player or planeswalker it's attacking.

Comment: The rule deal with lethal damage, and in this case damage is not lethal since it's prevented. Also, damage is dealt to creature before it's dealt to player or planeswalker, so there's no remaining damage because it's prevented...

Comment: @sinsedrix "lethal damage" is a game term, it doesn't actually have to kill the creature to be called "lethal damage". It says in the quote that you don't take into account abilities or effects that might prevent damage and save the creature.

Comment: @sinsedrix, Re "*in this case damage is not lethal since it's prevented.*", Read again. "*When checking for assigned lethal damage, take into account damage already marked on the creature and damage from other creatures that's being assigned during the same combat damage step, **but not any abilities or effects that might change the amount of damage that's actually dealt.***"